# If $A \in M_n(\mathbb C)$ is skew symmetric, $adj(A)$ is symmetric or skew symmetric depending on $n$ being even or odd

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

A symmetric matrix is a square matrix that is equal to its transpose.

A skew-symmetric (or antisymmetric) matrix is a square matrix whose transpose is also its negative.

1. Assume that $A \in M_n(\mathbb C)$ is a skew symmetric matrix.  Prove that $adj(A)$ is symmetric or skew symmetric depending on $n$ being even or odd.
2. If $A \in M_n(\mathbb C)$ is skew symmetric and $n$ is odd, then $A$ is not invertible.

Note :  I wrote $(adjA)^T=adj(A^T)=adj(-A)$ but i don't know what happens next.

Comment: What is $F$ here? And could you define $adj(A)$.

Comment: @JackyChong adj(A) is the adjucate matrix ... $F$ is $\mathbb C$ i forgot it ...

Comment: $A \cdot adj(A)=|A|, (-A)\cdot adj(-A)=|-A|=(-1)^n|A|.$

Comment: @mfl i don't get the connection between $A.adj(A)$ and $adj(A)^T$ ... would you please write an answer ?

Comment: You have that $A\cdot adj(A)=|A| I$ and $A\cdot adj(-A)=(-1)^{n+1}|A|I.$ Thus, if $A$ is invertible, we have $adj(-A)=(-1)^{n+1}adj(A),$ which is the identity you are looking for. Of course, it works also if $A$ is not invertible.

Comment: @mfl how does it work ? with dividing by zero?!?!

Comment: No. When you compute the adjugate of $-A$ you are computing determinants of order $n-1.$ But if $M$ has order $n-1$ then $|-M|=(-1)^{n-1}|M|.$ This is the reason. So, $adj(-A)=(-1)^{n-1} adj(A).$ (Note that $(-1)^{n-1}=(-1)^{n+1}).$

Comment: @mfl thank you :) i got it ... any idea about the second question?

Comment: $|A|=|A^T|=|-A|=-|A|$ where we have used that $A$ is skew-symmetric and then of odd order.